# importing ZFS pool from mirror child

Tags: zfs, high-availability

I created a ZFS mirror from two disks. Then, without exporting the created pool I moved one of the disks to another system. How can I get back the data from that mirror child on a different system?

I used the zdb command to get information about the pool here is the output:

```
zdb -l sde

------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'mypool'
    state: 2
    txg: 121
    pool_guid: 12279094248801560314
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'dse1051'
    top_guid: 5698356755932484628
    guid: 8107190423262889178
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'mirror'
        id: 0
        guid: 5698356755932484628
        metaslab_array: 256
        metaslab_shift: 27
        ashift: 9
        asize: 26828341248
        is_log: 0
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 12590988309290499730
            path: '/dev/sde1'
            whole_disk: 1
            create_txg: 4
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 8107190423262889178
            path: '/dev/sdf1'
            whole_disk: 1
            create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    labels = 0 1 2 3
```

I used the command

```
zpool import mypool
```

I also used the pool guid but I always get : `no such pool available`

Also `state: 2` means that the pool is **DEGRADED**, after using the command `zpool import -D` I got the below output:

```
   pool: mypool
     id: 12279094248801560314
  state: DEGRADED (DESTROYED)
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
    fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
 config:

    mypool      DEGRADED
      mirror-0  DEGRADED
        sde     FAULTED  corrupted data
        sde     ONLINE
```

Unfortunately, I still cannot import the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing trick was :
After using `zpool import -D`
we should use `zpool import -D mypool` not just `zpool import mypool`